# How i can Receive WSDL File from Mule SOAP Component?

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, soapui, mule-studio

i am using SOAP UI 4.6.2. Here i have created one XML file for WSDL. and i set to endpoint URL is `localhost:8081`. In mule which flow i need to create to fetch the data from SOAP UI.The following code is XML for WSDL. This code only used for in SOAP UI.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:out="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" xmlns:urn="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <out:notifications>
         <out:OrganizationId>?</out:OrganizationId>
         <out:ActionId>?</out:ActionId>
         <out:SessionId>?</out:SessionId>
         <out:EnterpriseUrl>?</out:EnterpriseUrl>
         <out:PartnerUrl>?</out:PartnerUrl>
         <!--1 to 100 repetitions:-->
         <out:Notification>
            <out:Id>?</out:Id>
            <out:sObject>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <urn:fieldsToNull>?</urn:fieldsToNull>
               <urn:Id>?</urn:Id>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <urn:FirstName>?</urn:FirstName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <urn:LastName>?</urn:LastName>
            </out:sObject>
         </out:Notification>
      </out:notifications>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Version: 3.5.0 Build Id: 201312091746 This is my mule configuration.

Comment: The configuration is the mule-config.xml. Please post the code. I would like to understand better if you need is to expose a web service in  mule and test it using soap ui? or how to get the wsdl and call a web service from mule?

Comment: how to get the WSDL and call a web service from mule? I don't Know how to create the flow. That's why i am asking. Above code is SOAP XML code. If i am running the code from SOAP UI 4.6.2 Software. How the Mule Receive the request. Please help. What is your concern. I don't have any mule code.

Comment: Soap ui is used to test the service created in any tech/way. Your post confused me. Hoping to have understood your question I have answered you question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Use the following links to learn creating web services in mule

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XML-only+SOAP+Web+Service+Example
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/SOAP+Web+Service+Security+Example

2.create the web service to accept your request xml which you have mentioned.

3.url?wsdl (eg:`http://localhost:8081?wsdl`) in web browser will give you the wsdl with which you can create the request in the soap ui (which will be same as the one you have above).

4.You will be able to hit your we service.

Comment: Thanks Its working now. can you tell me how to post data to other web application by using REST API or JSON. My actual data was XML format how can i post data to other web application via REST or JSON.